# Executing the commands stored in a crontab

Tags: bash, cron, crontab

I have setup a few commands to run every night using `cron`. When I don't leave my laptop running overnight, these commands will not be executed.  I can't use `anacron` because it's not available on my Mac.

What would be a one-liner that I can paste in a Terminal when I come in the morning and I want to run all the commands from my `crontab`?

Comment: Not an answer to the explicit question but a simple solution to the underlying problem: keep the commands in a script. Let cron run the script as a single job. Or you run the script in the morning instead.

Comment: Good point! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
crontab -l | cut -d ' ' -f 3- | (while read line; do (eval $line); done)
```

It lists all the content of the crontab, removes the `@daily` that appears at the front, reads each line in the resulting output, and executes it in a separate shell.

The reason to use a separate shell is that a number of these lines look like

```
cd somedir/somewhere; dosomething
```

They assume starting in the home directory, and will not change back to that place at the end.